# How to spawn an NPC that already has commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've got an NPC egg, fully customized it with commands and text, but I want to have it at multiple spots in my world. Is it possible to copy it or put it in a spawn egg or any other form of similar things that don't involve me manually recoding the NPC at every place I want it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi -  can you specify what kind of NPC eggs are you talking about? Since you mentioned "putting an NPC egg into a spawn egg" and it is not clear as to what you are referring to.